# Does Horizon work with Keystone and Swauth?

Tags: openstack

I have setup an all-in-one server with Swift and use Swauth to authentication. It working . I can use tools like CyberDuck or CloudBerry explorer to manage my objects on Swift. 
But I can login in Horizon with account create by Swauth.

Does Horizon work with Swauth?
If Yes so how can I configure?

Thank you!

This question was posted also in [openstack](https://answers.launchpad.net/horizon/+question/200382). A friend of mine posted it. We are working together :)

Answer (score 0):

Horizon doesn't natively authenticate against swauth (now called "tempauth" in the swift project), it uses Keystone (http://keystone.openstack.org) as the expected shared-authN system for OpenStack.

Comment: Swift's "TempAuth" middleware( http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/overview_auth.html ) and "Swauth" middleware ( https://github.com/gholt/swauth ) are not the same in the Swift project.